Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)
A few minutes ago, I was able to ssh into an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance using a key and a password. Now, with the same key and password, it is showing: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
I am the only one who has access to the instance and I have not changed any configuration.
I verified that the instance is running and so are the services deployed on it.

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; nor any command lines details as to how you logged in, as your details don't rule out user errors due to typo or other mistake.
